# Wiki proof of Lucas primality test

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have a question about one step in the proof:

Why does $a^{n-1} \equiv 1\ (\operatorname{mod} n)$ imply that $a$ and $n$ are coprime?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\rm a^{n-1}\! = 1\! +\! kn\:$ so $\rm\:d\mid a,n\:\Rightarrow\: d\mid 1 = a^{n-1}\!-kn$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another answer: What you wrote implies $a a^{n-2} \equiv 1\ (\operatorname{ mod }n)$. However, $a$ possesses an inverse $\operatorname{mod} n$ iff $(a,n)=1$. So what you wrote is only possible if $(a,n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

(Assume $n \ge 2$.) From Bézout's Identity, we know $a$ and $n$ are coprime iff:

$$ax + ny = 1$$

has integer solutions $x,y$. The equation $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ translates to the existence of integers $z, y$ such that:

$$za^{n-1} + ny = 1$$

Taking $x = za^{n-2}$ yields the desired equation above.

Comment: Is it actually iff? The Bezout's Identity I could find only states that given gcd(a,b), exist solutions to ax+by=gcd(a,b).

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity): "[...] every integer of the form $ax+by$ is a multiple of $d$". Thus $d$ divides $1$.

Comment: The trivial fact that $\rm\:ax+ny = 1\:\Rightarrow\: gcd(a,n) = 1\:$ is not Bezout's identity (which is the nontrivial *opposite* direction).

Comment: I don't see how this comment is relevant (I did carefully write _iff_). Perhaps I have taken a less elementary approach than would have sufficed, but there's not a law against that...

Comment: @Lord_Farin The point is that $\rm\:ax+ny = 1\:\Rightarrow\: gcd(a,n) = 1\:$ is true in *any* ring (cf. my answer), but the opposite direction (Bezout's Theorem) is true only in very special rings. For example, as in my answer, we can deduce $\rm\:gcd(a, ab+1) = 1\:$ in rings where Bezout's identity does not hold, e.g. $\rm\:a,b \in R[x,y],\:$ being bivariate polynomials, where, e.g. $\rm\:gcd(x,y) = 1,\:$ but there is no Bezout identity $\rm\:x f + y g = 1\ $ (else $\rm\: 0 = 1\:$ by evaluating at $\rm\:x=0,\, y=0).\ \ $

Comment: @MathGems: Thank you for your comprehensive comments; I certainly agree that your answer is more elegant and succinct, and therefore deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Lord_Farin My concern in not what answer is accepted or highest voted, etc. Rather, my concern is to help readers understand the essence of the matter: that the simple direction is a special case of a divisibility law $\rm\: c\mid a,b\:\Rightarrow\: c\mid r a + s b\:$ that is true in every ring (for reasons having nothing to do with Bezout's identity).